# drop down list for years

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to create a payment form. I am trying to create a payment form like the ones on the online shopping websites. I have created drop down lists for type of credit card and months but I'm not to sure about the year drop down list. Would I use the same code as I did for months and type of credit cards? Do I just put all the years manually or is the another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML nor JS don´t know `<credit_card_year>` tag.

So use `<select>` tag with next few (three, four?) years.

Comment: Needs more than 3-4. Although it's unusual, some cards have 10 year validity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Was just getting a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Manually is the safest choice but you can do it in JS or backend server..

Presume that the year starts on the current year.. then and you are using jQuery

```
var years = $('<select>');
var currnet_year = new Date().getFullYear();
 for(var i =1; i < 51; i++){
   var n_y =(currnet_year +i);
   years.append( $('<option>',{ text: (n_y ), value:n_y  }) );
 }
```

append the years everyware you want.